# How do you categorize graphic designers for game development?

Tags: graphics-design

I have hired a graphic designer locally and she is good at drawing things (cartoons, characters, etc.) and good at using Photoshop and Illustrator.

However, when we come to game UIs (such as the dialogs, buttons, etc.), she is not doing ok.

For game development, do you categorize graphic designers? Do you need more than one kind of graphic designer? especially for a small team (4-5 people)?

Comment: Please edit your question and remove "Do you need more than one kind of graphic designer? especially for a small team (4-5 people)?" This is really broad and situation specific and does not fit well in the context of this site.

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that in game development this role is typically referred to as "artist". Referring to them as a "designer" could be misleading because a "game designer" is completely different from a "graphic designer". When you use the full title it's clear what you mean, but be careful about being unclear when shortening the term.

Second, your question is somewhat circular. I mean, you ask:

> Do you need more than one kind of graphic designer?

Well, do *you?* What *we* need is pretty much irrelevant to what *you* need. I mean, you said she's good at drawing some things and not others. Obviously then you need someone else on your team who is good at that other stuff.